# Unsuccessful validation of login credentials in zapier

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, zapier, zapier-cli

This is my authentication.js file. upon entering login credentials , while setting up an account in action block, it accepts any input string and password hence the validation fails.

```js
var request = require('request');
var https = require('https');
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');

const testAuth = (z , bundle) => {
  return z.request({
      url: 'https://abc.xyz.com/api/login.json',
      method:'POST',
      body:JSON.stringify({
        'ms_request':{
          'user':
          {
            'api_key':'ABCD',
            'username':bundle.authData.username,
            'password':bundle.authData.password,
          }
        }
      }),
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 401) {
        throw new Error('wrong credentials');
      }
      return response.content;
    });
};

module.exports = {
  type: 'custom',
  fields: [
    {key: 'username', label: 'Username', required: true, type: 'string'},
    {key: 'password', label: 'Password', required: true, type: 'password'}
  ],
  test: testAuth,
  connectionLabel: '{{bundle.authData.username}}'
};
```

[In the given UI the action block accepts any given input string as username and password while connecting an account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqrP4.png)

Comment: Shouldn't the input take anything? You don't know what the user's input will be, so it seems like you should be ready for anything. Is the problem that the test never returns true?

Comment: User can add account by entering any string though it is invalid and is still able to connect an account which does not exist.

Comment: So the test always returns true? What status code does the api give when presented with bad auth?

Comment: API always gives 200 , but i have handled that by handling error. now its working properly.Thank you!